# React setstate into a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i send url parameter wtih react into "onchange" to "getcontent" ??
im trying many time and i cant !!! i want only get url parameter into onChange function and  sending to getContent function..

Sorry my poor English

```
class FetchDemo extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      posts: [],

      urlx: ''
    };

    getContent(url) {

         axios
           .get(url)
           .then(res => {
             const posts = res
               .data
               .Links
               .map(obj => obj);
             this.setState({ posts: posts, urlx: url });

             console.log('posts', posts);
           })
           .catch(error => {
             console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error);
           });

       }
```

> 

```
    onChange(e) {
         let myHistory = [];

         let self = this
         let index = self
           .select()
           .index();
         let dataItem = self
           .dataSource
          .view()[index];
         let urlb= dataItem.PlayList;

         if (urlb) {

          let grid = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");


           myHistory.push(dataItem);


         }

        // send urlb to getContent ?????
       }
```

//.........

Comment: Any reason you can't just call the method? `this.getContent(urlb)`

Comment: but i'm getting error as "this.getContent is not a function"

Comment: Can you share the `render` method? It looks like you have not properly bound the `onChange` method to the component instance. Add this to the end of your constructor: `this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)`

Comment: as @djfdev mentioned you're more than likely not binding `getContent` in your class. You should add `this.getContent = this.getContent.bind(this);` in your constructor or use babel babel transform class properties in conjunction with the closure pattern.

p.s. I down voted this question because you did not take the time to ensure your code was properly highlighted. Small portions of your code show incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell exactly what is going on in your limited code example, but a couple things:

1. Don't put `getContent(url)` inside your constructor.
2. Bind `getContent` in your constructor
3. Call `this.getContent` with your variable using (which will work,
   since `this` is bound in your constructor).

   ```
   class FetchDemo extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);

       this.state = {
         posts: [],
         urlx: '',
       };
       // bind your function to this
       this.getContent = this.getContent.bind(this);
     };

     getContent(url){
       axios
         .get(url)
         .then(res => {
           const posts = res.data.Links.map(obj => obj);
           this.setState({ posts: posts, urlx: url });
           console.log('posts', posts);
         })
         .catch(error => {
           console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error);
         });
     };

     onChange(e) {
       let myHistory = [];
       let self = this;
       let index = self.select().index();
       let dataItem = self.dataSource.view()[index];
       let urlb = dataItem.PlayList;

       if (urlb) {
         let grid = $('#listView').data('kendoListView');
         myHistory.push(dataItem);
         // call your internal function with hte variable
         this.getContent(urlb);
       }

     }

     render () {
       return (
         ...
       );
     }
   }
   ```